# Persistance behaviour of Camunda on user tasks

Tags: camunda

at our company we are going to use Camunda workflow engine for process automation. At the moment we are trying to define a reasonable workflow which mirrors our business process. We don't really know how to model (and then implement) the following scenario:

```
Start -> Service Task 1 -> User Task -> Gateway -> Service Task 2 (based on user choice in the User Task)
```

The Service Task 1 creates an object, which can be used by a user in the User Task. A user chooses (based on the state of the object created in Service Task 1 and on his rights) the next action to be executed on the object.

E.q. we have user A and user B. User A may edit the object, create a report, review it, forward it to another user, or complete the processing of the object. User B may ask for a review, forward the object to another user, or complete the processing, but only if the object was already reviewed by user A.

In order to offer to the user only the actions (gateway outcomming sequence flows / service tasks) he could choose from, we have to decide it (to filter the possible actions) after the Service Task 1 was already completed and the user logs in and chooses the process instance to go on.

How could this situation be propely modeled by bpmn? 
How would you implement it using camunda? Using some sort of Listeners, JavaDelegate implementations, something else?

Regards,
Iryna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if they are a lot of BPMN specialists on Stackoverflow but for modeling questions I would have a look at the [camunda network](http://network.camunda.org/forum).
There you can upload your BPMN files and ask for review (and comments can be added on the BPMN elements, neat feature)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just found that forum as well and it's of course better suited for my question. Thank you for your answer anyway!